# Is there any way to add dynamic plugins to composer

Tags: php, composer-php

Is there any way to add dynamic plugins to composer?
What I meant by plugins is designate a folder that will be loaded by composers autoloader without touching the `composer.lock` file, so end user will be able to simply drop a package in there and composer will just load it allowing my application to find and use classes from there.

edit:
Let me explain my use case, maybe that will help. I am working on an application that has both main features and optional features (shipped as extra packages). If end user will install a plugin and then I will ship him a new version of main application (with new modified composer.lock) it will end up with a conflict between changes done to the app and changes done by installing those plugins. I want to avoid those conflicts and fully automate the process.

Comment: yeah you could do that.

Comment: you could do `composer require <orgname or username>/repo:dev-branchname`

Comment: maybe have a cron job or something to check your folder, store the "repo"s in a json file and just read it then do require on composer

Comment: [this link](https://gemfury.com/help/php-composer-server/) might help

Comment: All of your suggestions will modify the `composer.lock`. 
I am looking for a solution that does not modify that file.

Comment: perhaps, make a backup, of which you have... then allow composer to do its thing, and when done from your script, just replace the lock file with the backup

Comment: its hacky but will work

Comment: Ok, let me explain my use case, maybe that will help. I am working on an application that has both main features and optional features (shipped as extra packages).
If end user will install a plugin and then I will ship him a new version of main application (with new modified `composer.lock`) it will end up with a conflict between changes done to the app and changes done by installing those plugins. I want to avoid those conflicts and fully automate the process.

Comment: you could use git submodules, and just use git to hack together some system to accomplish this

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it, not to the comment section. I don't see how this could be a good idea

Comment: Why not install everything through Composer the common way? Or install everything that is part of your "dynamic plugins" through anything else than Composer? When configuring the autoloader properly, you could write whatever you want to your own directories outside the vendor

Comment: You could create a (remote) script which returns changes to the composer.lock file based on the user's client id or something similar. You would have to keep the composer.lock file changes available for every version separately as well. What would keep users from simply overwriting the lock file with all you have in your package.json? Is the same change then required for it as well?